# Unable to create file inside docker container using Python SDK

Tags: python, docker

I am unable to create a file inside a Docker container, using latest Python SDK on Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

Here is what I do:

1. I use the Docker CLI to create a container based on Ubuntu, on a Ubuntu 16.04LTS host machine;
2. I create a createfile.py script which looks like this:

   ```
   import docker
   client = docker.from_env()
   container = client.containers.get('fbb206330c24')
   print container.exec_run(['echo', '123', '>', '/var/abc.txt'])
   ```

   with `fbb206330c24` being the id of the container.

The output is:

```
ExecResult(exit_code=0, output='123 > /var/abc.txt\n')
```

which looks OK to me.

3. I then run the following command on the host machine to SSH to the container:

   `docker exec -it fbb206330c24 bash`

then I try to look inside the `/var` directory, I expect there is an `abc.txt` file there. But there is none.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the input source for sh command from stdin to the input argument of string type:

```
container.exec_run(['sh', '-c', 'echo 123 > /var/abc.txt'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
print container.exec_run(['echo', '123', '>', '/var/abc.txt'])
```

to

```
print container.exec_run(['sh', '-c', 'echo', '123', '>', '/var/abc.txt'])
```

Related info: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/1637